# Historical report for configurable number of days

Tags: sql-server

I have a table of test runs, which have 3 runs daily. I need to show historical data for average of on load time

```
testID   testName   runID    date         LoadTime

1        Test1      r1      08-01-2016    2.04
1        Test1      r2      08-01-2016    2.02
1        Test1      r3      08-01-2016    2.01
2        Test2      r1      08-01-2016    2.04
2        Test2      r2      08-01-2016    2.02
2        Test2      r3      08-01-2016    2.01
1        Test1      r1      08-02-2016    2.00
1        Test1      r2      08-02-2016    2.04
1        Test1      r3      08-02-2016    2.05
2        Test2      r1      08-02-2016    2.03
2        Test2      r2      08-02-2016    2.02
2        Test2      r3      08-02-2016    2.04
.
.
.
.
```

Here we have historical data for 2 test. Each test has 3 runs per day and we have data for several months. I need historical data in below format

```
testID   testName   08-01-2016  08-02-2016 ........... 08-31-2016

1        Test1      2.04        2.05       ...........  2.01
2        Test2      2.02        2.05       ...........  2.01
```

Which means I will have number of rows equals unique testID and dates as columns. Data is average of 3 runs per day per test.

I know that we have to use Pivot here but main challenge is to get dynamic column names. e.g. above result is for August, however based on a date variable, I should get data for different month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Average, but your desired results looks like max

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2016-08-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2016-08-31'

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName([Date]) From Yourtable Where Date between @Date1 and @Date2  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [testID],[testName],' + @SQL + '
From (
        Select testID,testName,date,LoadTime 
        From YourTable
        Where Date Between '''+cast(@Date1 as varchar(10))+''' and '''+cast(@Date2 as varchar(10))+'''
     ) A
 Pivot (avg(LoadTime) For [Date] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
testID  testName    2016-08-01  2016-08-02
1       Test1       2.023333    2.030000
2       Test2       2.023333    2.030000
```

Comment: oh yes, actually that is dummy data and I thought no-one will notice :) accepting this answer

Comment: @gaurav If I had a nickle for every time my wife said that  :)